# comparar datatable com gridview

Tags: c#, datatable, gridview

minha dúvida é a seguinte:
eu tenho um gridview que eu populo ele com um data table de uma tabela chamada "Descontosdocliente", porem eu preciso de um botão que quando seja clicado ele vá em outra tabela chamada "setores" e vá percorrendo cada linha da tabela setores e depois verificar se o setor encontrado na tabela "setores" já está no datagrid.

eu tentei assim, mas nao estou tendo exito:

```
private void IncluiTodosSetores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tabela = Dados.carregaSetoresTodos();
    foreach (DataRow linha in tabela.Rows)
    {
        int achou = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in GridDesconto.Rows)
        {
            int codorig = Convert.ToInt16(linha["Codigo"]);
            int codgrid = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridViewRow.Cells["setor_codigo"].Value);
            if (codorig.ToString() == codgrid.ToString())
            {
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                achou = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (achou == 0)
        {
            //inclui o setor nao encointrado no grid
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nesse código seu acontece algum erro ou simplesmente ele não retorna nada? E só uma dúvida, porque você tá convertendo pra int e depois pra string?

Comment: ele não dá erro, mas tb não funciona...
esse grid é preenchido com os setores da loja em que o cliente tem desconto, porem as vezes algum setor é apagado por ele nao ter mais direito a desconto naquele setor. até ai tudo bem, mas de tempos em tempos, temos que por os setores novamente para ele, mas só os que ele ainda nao tem. entao esse codigo seria para isso: verificar se no grid tem todos os setores disponiveis e se nao tiver, incluir os faltantes...

Comment: a ideia era percorrer a tabela setores, regsitro por registro... e quando pegasse o codigo do setor, verificar se esse codigo já está no grid view e se nao estiver ai eu incluiria apenas ele, o faltante.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!!!!

Era um BREACK maledito a mais...

foi só comentar ele que funcionou...

Como eu mesmo resolvi, qual o procedimento para encerrar esse topico?

Obrigado a todos...

```
private void IncluiTodosSetores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tabela = Dados.carregaSetoresTodos();
    foreach (DataRow linha in tabela.Rows)
    {

        //MessageBox.Show(linha["Codigo"].ToString());

        int achou = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in GridDesconto.Rows)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(dataGridViewRow.Cells["setor_codigo"].Value.ToString());

            int codorig = Convert.ToInt16(linha["Codigo"]);
            int codgrid = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridViewRow.Cells["setor_codigo"].Value);
            if (codorig.ToString() == codgrid.ToString())
            {
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                achou = 0;
               // break;
            }
        }

        if (achou == 0)
        {
            //inclui o setor nao encointrado no grid
            MessageBox.Show(linha["Codigo"].ToString());

        }
    }
}
```